# Node.js .. Socket.io connection increase on every page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

i hope you solve my problem.

---

i have this code in "app.js" file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const stores = require('./routes/r_stores');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.io=io;

app.use('/stores',stores);
// update question
io.on('connection',function(socket){
  console.log("IO APP CONNECTED  ");
  socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    console.log("IO APP DISCONNECT  ");
  }) 
})
server.listen(3080, function () {
    console.log('listening on port 3080');
});
```

And in the "r_stores.js" file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
   req.app.io.on('connection', function(socket){
          console.log("IO STORES CONNECTED");
          socket.on('disconnect',function(){
            console.log("IO STORES DISCONNECTED");
          })
   })
})
module.exports = router;
```

**The problem when the client refresh the page , Socket IO increase the connection for one user , and when i emit a message it's sent to the client by the number of connection.**

when refresh , the console show this

On First refresh

> IO APP CONNECTED
>
> IO STORES CONNECTED

On Second refresh

> IO APP CONNECTED
>
> IO STORES CONNECTED
>
> IO STORES CONNECTED

On Third refresh

> IO APP CONNECTED
>
> IO STORES CONNECTED
>
> IO STORES CONNECTED
>
> IO STORES CONNECTED

Comment: I think the client side code connects to the io server on start/init, this causes it to connect to the websocket on every refresh

Comment: i used socket io in "app.js" and it works fine even multiple refresh .
the problem with `router.get ('/')` and export .. i mean with module.

Comment: Why you socket initialized in a router. Socket and Router are Different When you call get route method first time, socket object first time created, when you call again it's another object created, that means when you call two time routes its create two socket object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the recorded event listeners by console logging the `io.sockets`

```
Namespace {
  _events:
   { connection: [ [Function], [Function], [Function], [Function] ] },
  _eventsCount: 1 }
```

To fix your problem, simply put this condition before you initialize the socket connection

```
  if(io.sockets._events == undefined) {
    io.on('connection', socket => {
      ...
    });
  }
```

In case there are other event listeners aside from `connection`

```
  if(!('connection' in io.sockets._events)) {
    io.on('connection', socket => {
      ...
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you put:

```
 req.app.io.on('connection', function(socket){...}
```

inside an `app.get()`.  That means that every time that route is hit, you add yet another `io.on('connection', ...)` handler leading to duplicate event handlers.

You don't actually have too many sockets connected, you are just outputting duplicate messages to the console because of duplicate event handlers.  If you looked at the actual number of connected sockets, you would find the appropriate number are actually there.

You should pretty much **NEVER install event handlers inside a route handler** because every time that route is hit, you add yet another event handler and duplicates accumulate (which usually causes problems).

You don't show what you're trying to accomplish in that route so I can't really offer a solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve.  You can move the `io.on('connection', ...)` outside the route to the top level of the module and then you will have one in that module, but won't be creating duplicate event handlers every time that route is hit.

If what you were really trying to do is to be able to send a message to the socket.io connect for the client that requested this route, then that's a more complicated thing to do.  If this is a route that serves an HTML page (as opposed to an Ajax call from an already loaded page) which it looks like since it's the `/` route, then you simply can't send to that page's socket.io connection in the route handler because it's a new page and it has not yet established it's socket.io connection (heck the page hasn't even been sent to the browser yet).  You have no way of communicating with something that has not yet connected.  Probably, whatever you want to send over socket.io, you should just render into the page as Javascript state that the page can access when it first runs or include already rendered HTML state.

Comment: How can i use Socket.io in "app.js" with `req` and `sessions` because i want to use `req.sessionID` and `req.session.memberId` which stored before .
note : i use  express-session 
i used this function `app.use(function(req,res){ console.log(req.sessionId) })`
it print the session id but the router (module) doesn't render .

Comment: @AliHassan - I do not understand what you were asking in that comment.  Please describe in words (and code) what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i want to use socket with sessions .

Comment: @AliHassan - Well, your question says nothing about that so far.  And, you show no code in your question at all that uses a session.  Maybe this is what you want: [express-socket.io-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session).

Comment: @jfrienf00 - Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

When you connect with server you can keep this information in the localStorage for example. After refresh check if element is available in localStorage if it's false send information to server that new user connected.

Comment: i updated the question .. in  app.js file i use ** `io.on('connetion')` ** and when the client refresh it connect once only.
the problem with ** `router.get('/')` ** and export the router every refresh .
i can't solve this problem -_-

Comment: This answer isn't what is causing the OP's issue.